# IsNot Nothing is failing

Tags: vb.net

I have seen similar questions and as I have to work with VB.net for a project I am stuck with fairly simple thing.

```
If (myValue IsNot Nothing) And (myValue.Length > 12) Then
    ' do some stuff
End If
```

Now when myValue is Nothing it gives me null reference exception. I have also tried,

```
If (Not myValue Is Nothing) And (myValue.Length > 12) Then
    ' do some stuff
End If
```

In C# which I am very much used it is very easy but in VB.net I am not finding nay way.

Comment: use `AndAlso` to short circuit the second test otherwise it will evaluate it and fail

Comment: AND in vb is like & in C#. AndAlso is like &&

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`AndAlso`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) instead of `And` (and `OrElse` instead of `Or`).

`AndAlso` performs a **short-circuiting** logical conjunction on two expressions. `And`
 will evaluate both even if the first already returned `False`.

Side-note: you should also use the [`If`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) instead of the old VB function [`IIf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=VS.90).aspx) for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't knew about AndAlso at all. I was just curious that whether IsNot Nothing and String.IsNullOrEmpty will do the same job? KIndly just comment on this. Regards

Comment: Instead of the explicit null check you can also use String.IsNullOrEmpty.